# Android clear download manager history without deleting file

Tags: android, download-manager

I use the download manager to download a file and install it.

I'm curious if there is a way to remove it from the downloads history without actually deleting the file from disk?

As far as I know there is no callback to tell if the user installed the file or not so I would like to leave it on disk, but remove it from the downloads history only.

Here is my download code:

// Create download manager
        final DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(appURL));

```
    // Save to here
    request.setDestinationUri(this.apkUri);

    // Retrieve system download service
    final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    // Queue request
    manager.enqueue(request);

    // Will fire off and perform installation when download completes
    BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent)
        {
            performInstall();
            ctxt.unregisterReceiver(this);
            //finish();
        }
    };

    context.registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

And one other thing I'm curious about is in my broadcast receiver is finish() necessary? I'm calling this from a helper class so I can't access the finish function inside of it for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Before queueing :

- Add a suffix ".download" to download local path

OnReceive callback :

- get local uri from DM download column (src)
- remove ".download" suffix from Uri (dst)
- rename "src" to "dst"
- remove ID from download manager

Result : file still on disk and DM cleaned